# Spark log- "min key = null, max key = null" while reading ORC file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orc

I am trying to join a Dataframe(say 100 records) with an ORC file with 100 million records through Spark(can increase to 4-5 billion, 25 bytes each record). It is also created using Spark hiveContext API.

**ORC File Creation Code**

```
//fsdtRdd is JavaRDD, fsdtSchema is StructType schema
DataFrame fsdtDf = hiveContext.createDataFrame(fsdtRdd,fsdtSchema);
fsdtDf.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).orc("orcFileToRead");
```

**ORC File Reading Code**

```
HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(sparkContext);
DataFrame orcFileData= hiveContext.read().orc("orcFileToRead");
// allRecords is dataframe
DataFrame processDf = allRecords.join(orcFileData,allRecords.col("id").equalTo(orcFileData.col("id").as("ID")),"left_outer_join");
processDf.show();
```

**Spark Logs while reading (from local)**

```
Input split: file:/C:/spark/orcFileToRead/part-r-00024-b708c946-0d49-4073-9cd1-5cc46bd5972b.orc:0+3163348
min key = null, max key = null
Reading ORC rows from file:/C:/spark/orcFileToRead/part-r-00024-b708c946-0d49-4073-9cd1-5cc46bd5972b.orc with {include: [true, true, true], offset: 0, length: 9223372036854775807}
Finished task 55.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 59). 2455 bytes result sent to driver
Starting task 56.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 60, localhost, partition 56,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2220 bytes)
Finished task 55.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 59) in 5846 ms on localhost (56/84)
Running task 56.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 60)
```

Although the Spark job completes successfully, I think, its not able to utilize ORC index file capability and thus checks through entire block of ORC data before moving on.

**Question**

-- Is it a normal behaviour, or I have to set any configuration before saving the data in ORC format?

-- If it is ***NORMAL***, what is the best way to join so that we discard non-matching records on the disk level(maybe only the index file for ORC data is loaded)?